# Computing linux core file size from headers

Tags: linux, elf, coredump

I'm trying to write C code that will compute Linux core dump file size based on it's ELF header. This is needed since I'm getting it piped to STDIN and need to pass it on, specifying it's size first, without actually writing it to a file. Reading the whole file to memory is also not an option.

First of all, I'm looking into core dump header:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, big endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              CORE (Core file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         257
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0

There are no sections in this file.

There are no sections to group in this file.
```

Next, I'm reading the program headers in a loop and taking sum of all FileSiz fields.
My assumption was that (ELF header size) + (Program header size)*(Number of program headers) + (Sum of all sergment sizes) will give me the overall file size. However, this is not the case. In my case I'm getting actual file of size 729088000 bytes while the above math gives me 729054616 bytes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the problem. The overall file size can be computed by taking the program header with the biggest offset and adding the file size to it, since the core file consists only from headers and segments.

E.g. if you read the program headers by readelf, and you take a look on the last entries:

```
  LOAD           0x00000000287d0000 0x000000557d5c0000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000002730000 0x0000000002730000  RW     10000
  LOAD           0x000000002af00000 0x000000557fcf0000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000010000 0x0000000000010000         10000
  LOAD           0x000000002af10000 0x000000557fd00000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000007f0000 0x00000000007f0000  RWE    10000
  LOAD           0x000000002b710000 0x000000ffffe70000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000040000 0x0000000000040000  RW     10000
```

Then the file size or the core dump will actually be 0x2b710000 + 0x40000

Comment: This answer is *completely* wrong, and the premise of the question is false.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to write C code that will compute Linux core dump file size based on it's ELF header.

This is impossible to do, because

- with dynamic linking, you have *many* different `ELF` headers, and each shared library will contribute to the final `core` file size, and
- dynamically allocated memory (usually the *most important* part of the core dump) is not described by the `ELF` header *at all*, and can be 10, 100 or 1000 times bigger than any `.data` from the executable.

However, it *is* possible to determine core size *if* you have managed to stop the executable *and* have access to its `/proc/$pid/maps`: the [google userspace coredumper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/) does exactly that.